# How to get the values for "set root" in menuentry while setting password for GRUB2 on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, boot, grub2

I need to disable single user mode on my servers running CentOS 7. I read the RedHat documentation on what goes to `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` and how to encrypt the password and all but one details makes sense. An example entry form RedHat docs is:

```
menuentry 'Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server' --unrestricted {
set root=(hd0,msdos1)
linux   /vmlinuz
}
```

Where (`hd0`, `msdos1`) is GRUB2 `/boot` location.

How do I find what this values is on my system?

I was hoping `fstab` would tell me that but it says:

```
UUID=0cc23cc1-3c58-4cd5-9999-6ccc206ccc54 /boot    xfs     defaults        0 0
```